# Blur background when modal is opened

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

So right now the modal appears when the button (in the bottom right corner) is pushed however I would like the background to be blurred when the modal is open.  I would also like the modal to slide up from the bottom.  Right now it just appears when the button is pushed.  For a cherry on top, I would love to have the action button turn white when the modal is open. Here is the code below:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ActionButton from "../../components/ActionButton";
import AddEventActionCard from "../../components/AddEventActionCard";

import AppHeader from "../../components/AppHeader";
import FooterNav from "../../components/FooterNav";
import "../Upcoming_Events/UpcomingEvents.css";

const UpcomingEvents = () => {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);

  return (
    <div>
      <AppHeader />
      <div className="upcoming-container">
        <div className="upcoming-card-container">
          <div className="upcoming-card-top-header">Upcoming Events</div>
          <div className="upcoming-card-top-events-scroll-container"></div>
        </div>
        {click ? <AddEventActionCard /> : ""}
        <div onClick={handleClick}>
          <ActionButton />
        </div>
      </div>
      <FooterNav />
    </div>
  );
};

export default UpcomingEvents;
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8SCG.png)

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first of all, you can make an overlay screen with position **fixed** to make sure that whenever the user will scroll the modal will still be on the screen and give the overlay screen any blurred color (personally, I used #33333354 in my latest project). the overlay will be like the following:

make an outer div that surrounds the modal content itself and give position fixed with left and bottom zero and also width and height 100% to make sure that they're filling out the hole screen.

the last tip I wanna leave, is that the recommended way to build good modals is to use Portals in React, it simply allows you to render a div or container generally, in any part of the DOM outside the parent's DOM tree, it effectively avoids z-index and overlap problems. refer to the official docs for furthermore details https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal

I hope I helped you and please leave any comments if anything of my talk wasn't clear enough!